# Como pasar un listbox por parametro en C#

Tags: c#, listbox

como andan ? Les comento, estoy haciendo un sistema en visual studio con windows form en C# y queria hacer una clase "Query" para ponerte las consultas  a la base de datos. Se me complico aca cuando tengo que llenar una listbox. Se me ocurrio pasar por referencia a la funcion Consulta_BuscarCalle (la cual pertenece a la clase Query). La llamada la hago desde el form llamado RegistrarCliente y le pasaria como parametros la listbox que pertenece a este form. Mi codigo es este:

```
private void BuscarCalleRegCliente()
    {
        lsbxCallesRegCliente.Items.Clear();
        MySqlConnection conex = ConexionBD.conexionDevuelve();
        conex.Open();
        string query = "Select nomCalle from calles where nomCalle like'%" + txtNomCalleRegCliente.Text + "%'";
        using (MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(query, conex))
        {
            using (MySqlDataReader red = com.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (red.Read())
                {
                    lsbxCallesRegCliente.Items.Add(red[0].ToString());
                }
                red.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Como hago para meter todo ese codigo en la funcion  Consulta_BuscarCalle y pasarle parametro por referencia la listbox llamada lsbxCallesRegCliente para llenarla desde la misma funcion? Muchas gracias, saludos!

---

Hice todo tal cual me pusiste, el tema es que no esta haciendo una parte del codigo. Te muestro:

La funcion quedo asi:

```
public static List<string> BuscarCalle(string nombre)
    {
        List<string> listCalles = new List<string>();
        MySqlConnection conex = ConexionBD.conexionDevuelve();
        conex.Open();
        string query = "Select nomCalle from calles where nomCalle like'% + ?nombre + %'";
        using (MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(query, conex))
        {
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("?nombre", nombre);
            using (MySqlDataReader red = com.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (red.Read())
                {
                    listCalles.Add(red[0].ToString());
                }
                red.Close();
            }
        }
        return listCalles;
    }
```

El using que tiene el datareader no lo pasa, como que lo saltea. Y no me trae ningun dato. Que hice mal?

Edito:
Lo solucione cambiando el nombre por @nombre y cambiando lo de dentro del Parameters.AddWithValue. Quedo asi:

```
public static List<string> BuscarCalle(string nombre)
    {
        List<string> listCalles = new List<string>();
        MySqlConnection conex = ConexionBD.conexionDevuelve();
        conex.Open();
        string query = "Select nomCalle from calles where nomCalle like @nombre";
        using (MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(query, conex))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("primer using");
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", "%"+ nombre+"%");
            using (MySqlDataReader red = com.ExecuteReader())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("lee el read");
                if (red.Read())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("dentro del while");
                    listCalles.Add(red[0].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No lee");
                }

            }
        }
        return listCalles;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tienes que pasarle ningun componente `listBox` a esa funcion, porque no deberia ser su resposabilidad cargarlo, solo deberia devolver los datos, como ser:

```
private List<string> BuscarCalleRegCliente(string nombre)
{
    List<string> listCalles = new List<string>();
    MySqlConnection conex = ConexionBD.conexionDevuelve();
    conex.Open();

    string query = "Select nomCalle from calles where nomCalle like '%' + ?nombre + '%'";
    using (MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(query, conex))
    {
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("?nombre", nombre);
        using (MySqlDataReader red = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (red.Read())
            {
                listCalles.Add(red[0].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    return listCalles;
}
```

y luego desde la UI acceder al control para asignar los datos

```
var result = queryClass.BuscarCalleRegCliente(txtNomCalleRegCliente.Text);

lsbxCallesRegCliente.Items.Clear();
foreach(var item in result)
{
    lsbxCallesRegCliente.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: faltaria el return result verdad?

Comment: si es verdad ahi lo arreglo

Comment: com.Parameters.AddWithValue("?nombre", nombre);

Que haria esto?

Comment: es la definicion del parametro que asigna el valor al select

Comment: Que Using tengo que poner para que me tome el parameteres.Add ese?

Comment: ningun using el objeto MySqlCommand tiene esta propiedad Parameters